# How to place textview in the middle relative layout?

Tags: android

I was just wondering what kind of relative layout parameters would I need to use to place a text view in the middle of an Image View. If this is not possible how else would I do so.

Answer (score 2):

You can use RelativeLayout, set the image as the background and use [Center_In_parent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#CENTER_IN_PARENT) for the textview.

Answer (score 1):

```
android:centerInParent="true"
```

or

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

or

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

You can use any of them depending on your requirement

Answer (score 0):

ImageView is not a view group, so you can't do that exactly.

What you need to do is to put both your ImageView and your textview inside a framelayout. Then center your textview using android:centerInParent="true".

Answer (score 0):

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;//set the relative layout
text=new TextView(context);
ImageView image=new ImageView(context); 

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageParams = new      
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textParams = new     
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
textParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
imageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
relativeLayout.addView(image,imageParams);
relativeLayout.addView(text,textParams);
```